# Count of unique days grouped by value - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm aiming to assign a cumulative count of unique days to a new column in a pandas df. It should count the number of unique days, gathered from `Date`, grouped by `Code` and `Item`. Once consecutive values in `Code` or `Item` are broken, the count should reset to 0.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Date":['2023-03-01', '2023-03-01', '2023-03-01', '2023-03-04', '2023-03-06', '2023-03-06', '2023-03-07', '2023-03-08', '2023-03-09','2023-03-01', '2023-03-02', '2023-03-03', '2023-03-03', '2023-03-03','2023-03-03', '2023-03-04', '2023-03-05', '2023-03-06'],
           "Code":['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y'],    
           "Item":['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'], 
           })
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df['Daily_Count'] = df.groupby(['Code', 'Item', df['Date'].dt.date]).cumcount()
```

Intended output:

```
   Date Code Item  Daily_Count
0  2023-03-01    X    A      1
1  2023-03-01    X    A      1
2  2023-03-01    X    A      1
3  2023-03-04    X    B      1
4  2023-03-06    X    B      2
5  2023-03-06    X    B      2
6  2023-03-07    X    B      3
7  2023-03-08    X    A      1
8  2023-03-09    X    A      2
9  2023-03-01    Y    A      1
10 2023-03-02    Y    A      2
11 2023-03-03    Y    A      3
12 2023-03-03    Y    A      3
13 2023-03-03    Y    A      3
14 2023-03-03    Y    A      3
15 2023-03-04    Y    A      4
16 2023-03-05    Y    A      5
17 2023-03-06    Y    A      6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group your values into `(Code, Item)` groups, which you can do by comparing those values against their previous values, and starting a new group whenever one of them changes:

```py
g = (df[['Code','Item']] != df[['Code', 'Item']].shift()).any(axis=1).cumsum()
# 0    1
# 1    1
# 2    1
# 3    2
# 4    2
# 5    2
# 6    2
# 7    3
# 8    3
```

You can then group your dataframe using these values, and sum the number of times the `Date` changes in each group:

```py
df['Daily_Count'] = df.groupby(g)['Date'].transform(lambda g:(g != g.shift()).cumsum())
```

Output:

```
         Date Code Item  Daily_Count
0  2023-03-01    X    A            1
1  2023-03-01    X    A            1
2  2023-03-01    X    A            1
3  2023-03-04    X    B            1
4  2023-03-06    X    B            2
5  2023-03-06    X    B            2
6  2023-03-07    X    B            3
7  2023-03-08    X    A            1
8  2023-03-09    X    A            2
9  2023-03-01    Y    A            1
10 2023-03-02    Y    A            2
11 2023-03-03    Y    A            3
12 2023-03-03    Y    A            3
13 2023-03-03    Y    A            3
14 2023-03-03    Y    A            3
15 2023-03-04    Y    A            4
16 2023-03-05    Y    A            5
17 2023-03-06    Y    A            6
```

Comment: Note that this requires the dates to be consecutive, if you want the real count you'd have to `transform ('first')` the date then `rsub` the current date ;)

Comment: @mozway OP just wants a cumulative count of days, I don't think they necessarily have to be consecutive, although it's not clear from the question. If that was the case, then yeah, some date math would have to happen. I'll wait to see what (if anything) OP comments.

Comment: Sorry, I'll rework the question. I do need dates to be considered.

Comment: @jonboy so do you want a count of *different* dates for each `Code,Item` pair? If so, are the dates always in increasing order?

Comment: Somewhat. The only caveat is it has to reset if a sequence is broken though. So it's not really a count of different dates for  `Code, Item`.

Comment: @jonboy are the sequences consecutive dates?

Comment: `Code, Item` determine the sequence. Unique values in `Code` may contain multiple values in `Item`. For each of these sequences, the `Date` column will be variable. As in, each row will not necessarily be a consecutive date. I want to assign a running count of days for each group of `Code, Item`

Comment: @jonboy So you want a running count of *different* days?

Comment: Yes, but grouped by `Code, Item` as dates will restart on unique vales in `Code`

Comment: @jonboy sorry that took a while. Thanks for the extra data, that really helped. Anyway, please see my edit, I think that is what you want.